# jQuery ajax request with promise not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, internet-explorer-9

Here is a class I made which uses YQL to do Google Translate.

```
var Translator = {
    source: 'ro', // default
    target: 'en', // default
    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from google.translate where q="',
    urlRemaining: '";&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=',
    diacritics: Array(),
    newCharacters: Array(),

    replaceAll: function( string, replace, replaceWith ) {
        return string.replace( new RegExp( replace, 'g' ), replaceWith );
    },

    replaceDiacritics: function( text ) {
        string = text;

        // diacritics and newCharacters should be arrays of the same length
        // diacritics should only be specified in lowercase - uppercased version will be assumed
        // durring the process
        for ( i = 0; i < this.diacritics.length; i++ ) {
            string = this.replaceAll( string, this.diacritics[i], this.newCharacters[i] );
            string = this.replaceAll( string, this.diacritics[i].toUpperCase(), this.newCharacters[i].toUpperCase() );
        }

        return string;
    },

    translate: function( text, target, source ) {
        target = target || this.target;
        source = source || this.source;

        return $.ajax({
            url: this.url + encodeURIComponent( this.replaceDiacritics( text ) ) + '" and source="' + source + '" and target="' + target + this.urlRemaining,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        });
    },

    spitResult: function( x, container ) {
        x.success(function(realData) {
            $report = realData.query.results.json.sentences;
            $result = '';
            if ($.isArray($report)) {
                for (i = 0; i < $report.length; i++) {
                    $result += $report[i].trans;
                }
            } else {
                $result = $report.trans;
            }

            if (container instanceof jQuery) {
                container.html($result);
            } else {
                container.innerHTML = $result;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And now I'm calling it on a set of elements in the page

```
promises = Array();

Translator.diacritics = Array('ă', 'â', 'î', 'ș', 'ț');
Translator.newCharacters = Array('a', 'a', 'i', 's', 't');

$('.translate').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    promises[promises.length] = Translator.translate($this.html(), 'en', 'ro');
    Translator.spitResult(promises[promises.length-1], $this);
});
```

This is working no problem with Firefox and Chrome. However, as usual, Internet Explorer (9 in my case) seems to be the problem. From what I've been able to deduce it resides in the promise resolver (`Translate.spitResult`) - which is called, but no data seem to be passed to it. I looked at it in the console. The promise array element is populated with 3 objects (which I am sure is normal), but it is:

```
readyState: 0
responseJSON: undefined, status: 0
statusText: "No Transfer".
```

I tried removing the diacritics function (now I'm not exactly sure why, because there should have been a response anyway), I also tried `cache: false` mode on the ajax call, but to no avail.

Does anyone know what could be the matter ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: +1 for _as usual, Internet Explorer (9 in my case) seems to be the problem_

Comment: please add a link to the working code so we can have a look without having to setup everything ourselves, thanks

Comment: @EmmanuelBucur so no data is passed to the spitResult() or the success() handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes Internet Explorer is your problem...
Check http://caniuse.com/#search=promise

I think you can use a polyfill (https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) if that's the problem, never tried a polyfill for promises but it will work like a charm for sure

Comment: Please take a minute to explain what the links you've posted are referencing.  An answer should be able to live without relying on external sources.

Comment: maybe a missread the question, for a moment I understood that the problem was that IE9 does not support promises so I linked the promises support and the polyfill to enable the use of promises on browsers that does not support it. But I may be wrong because i don't see him using promises now.